# Can you please identify this set?

Tags: set-identification

I got this set but it is missing pieces and I am trying to figure out which set it is.  Can you help please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m pretty sure that rc car was in a lego advent calendar a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Looking up all sets that have this piece in tan, had me guessing at *[Set #5771-1 Hillside House](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5771-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

**EDIT**:  At least two maybe a third set...

[image]

Looking at white fence in upper right corner of 2nd pic.

[*Set #3938 Andrea's Bunny House.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3938-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Again looking at that upper right hand corner of 2nd pic.

I spy with my little eye a tan cone that is not in the previous sets.

*[Set #Set 3937 Olivia's Speedboat](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3937-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

Possible 4th???

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir.  Great help

Comment: You can see the raised green yard area in the pictures.

Comment: Looks like the possibility of more sets.  My initial search was for the white fence in the upper right hand corner of the 2nd picture.  Got back too many results, so I moved on the the tan window, but...  there is no fence piece in the Hillside House set, nor is there a tan cone... Let's search some more...

Comment: It's not fair that you keep adding valuable observations, but I can't keep adding +1s :)

Comment: Hey Z, I think there's a forth! I saw the r/c car in set earlier,  but now I can't find it...

Comment: The previous three sets came out around 2011-12, so I looking at sets release in those years for the 4th set...